# How can i do insert more data with insert query with more select statment linqToSQL?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, linq, linq-to-sql

How can i use `insert into myTABLE (. . . .. . ) select * from(.......)`. I try to write some linq query but i can not. Look please linq query.

**SQL:**

```
INSERT INTO ActualAmountsByLocation (ItemBarcode, Location, LocationName, Amount, isCustomerItem, LastUpdate)
   SELECT * FROM 
      (SELECT DISTINCT 
           m.ItemBarcode, 
           m.ToLocationType + m.ToNo AS Location,
           l.shortdesc AS LocationName,  
           dbo.spGetActualAmountByLocation(m.ItemBarcode, m.ToLocationType + m.ToNo) AS Amount, 
           0 AS isCustomerItem,
           GETDATE() AS LastUpdate 
       FROM 
           dbo.StockMovement m, RefLocations l 
       WHERE 
           m.ToLocationType = 'L' 
           AND m.ToLocationType + m.ToNo = l.code 
           AND m.ItemBarcode = @Barcode 
           AND m.TransactionType = 1
       ) a  
  ORDER BY ItemBarcode, Location

UPDATE ActualAmountsByLocation 
SET isCustomerItem = 1 
WHERE ItemBarcode IN 
      (SELECT barcode FROM StockMaterials WHERE barcode = @Barcode AND ownership = 1)

UPDATE ActualAmountsByLocation 
SET isCustomerItem = 1
WHERE ItemBarcode IN 
      (SELECT barcode FROM StockTools WHERE barcode = @Barcode AND ownership = 1)

UPDATE ActualAmountsByLocation 
SET isCustomerItem = 1 
WHERE ItemBarcode IN 
      (SELECT barcode FROM StockComponents WHERE barcode = @Barcode AND ownership = 1)

SET @ReturnMsg = RTRIM(@ReturnMsg) + 'E25: Transaction completed successfully ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
```

**Linq:**

```
if (ToLocationType == 'L')
{
   var stokRefLocation = (from m in stockMovementCtx.StockMovements
                          from l in stockMovementCtx.RefLocations
                          where m.ToLocationType == 'L' && m.ToLocationType + m.ToNo == l.code && m.ItemBarcode == Barcode && m.TransactionType == 1
                          orderby m.ItemBarcode, l.shortdesc
                          select new
                          {
                             myItemBarcode= m.ItemBarcode,
                             myLocation = m.ToNo + m.ToNo,
                             myLocationName = l.shortdesc,
                             myAmount = stockMovementCtx.spGetActualAmountByLocation(m.ItemBarcode, m.ToLocationType + m.ToNo),
                                                  myIsCustomerItem = 0,
                                                  myLastUpdate = DateTime.Now
                                              }).Distinct();

   var stokMovement2 = new ActualAmountsByLocation()
                       { 
                           ItemBarcode = stokRefLocation. //.. how can i do that? I want to see stokRefLocation.myItemBarcode
                       }
                   }
               }
```

Comment: IF you already have this in T-SQL, then why do you want to change that to Linq-to-SQL? L2S is great for handling single records and its relations, or a small collection of rows. It's not really the champion when it comes to handling complex SQL - that's why we have SQL. Use the right tool for the job - leave this in T-SQL, and call it from your app using standard ADO.NET.

Answer (score 1):

The truth is that L2S isn't really optimised for that sort of operation.  You could create a stored procedure to do it (that can be added to your L2S datacontext for execution) or write is as a direct database command.

Typically in an ORM you'd update all the records, then submit the changes on the datacontext.  If that's too slow, then consider optimising by one of the above methods.